# How to rotate a character or string by 90 or 180 degree in python?

Tags: python

I want to write a code that will take an input of "python" and give an output of"uoɥʇʎd"

Comment: Use the [upsidedown package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/upsidedown/0.3)

Answer (score 3):

There is definitely a library out there that can complete this task, like this package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/upsidedown/0.3 (MIT licensed)

In use:

```
import upsidedown
print upsidedown.transform('hello world!')
```

Output:

```
¡pꞁɹoʍ oꞁꞁǝɥ
```

Comment: If i want to do this by my own function what should i do?

Comment: @OmarFarukSazib Although it would be more difficult to do it yourself, take a look at the upsidedown module github repo - all the code is listed there, given you an idea of what to do